# How to call site name in PHP block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a block in my footer that I currently use to display a copyright message using PHP, like so:

```
Copyright © <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
```

I'd like to add the site name to that code snippet, dynamically instead of typing the name. How can I do so?

So the end result would be:

```
Copyright © <?php echo date("Y"); ?> [[[php code to display site name goes here]]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) to get the site name, but you shouldn't use it directly in the template file or you could break caching.

Instead, define a preprocess function in your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['site_name'] = variable_get('site_name', 'Default');
}
```

Then you can use this in the template file:

```
Copyright © <?php echo date("Y"); ?> <?php echo $site_name; ?>
```

Before doing that, though, check whether you already have `$site_name` available in page.tpl.php. Some themes add it for you, some don't.

Comment: I followed those two steps, but it did not work. Instead, I received the following error message:  " ×
Error message
Notice: Undefined variable: site_name in eval() (line 1 of /home/mysite/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code)."

Comment: My page.tpl.php file does have this:  "<?php print $site_name; ?>". However, the suggestions above still do not work. I cleared cache, no effect.

Comment: Did you replace "MYTHEME" with the name of your theme?

Comment: If this is in a block, then preprocessing the page won't do it, rather, you are going to have to put the variable_get()s inside it, and since the error is coming from the php module, this suggests you are doing this through the Block UI and using the php input filter that brings up all sorts of other nastiness I won't go into here...

Comment: I did, but no luck. My theme name is "bootstrap_qcc" so my code says "bootstrap_qcc_preprocess_page..."

Comment: Yes, I am doing adding the php via the Block UI. Is this not recommended?

Comment: Putting a `<?php print variable_get('site_name', 'Default'); ?>` in there should do what you are wanting then.  As for if it's recommended, I'd moreso suggest creating a block in a custom module instead as you can see the code, eg, it's not in the database, plus you have more control over it, eg, typos, plus any potential security issues.

Comment: @hockey2112 I'm very sorry, even though it's in the title and first line of the question, I somehow missed that you were doing this in a block. I'll delete this answer once you've had a chance to read Jimajamma's suggestions. If you could let me know I'd be grateful

Comment: @Jimajamma that worked perfectly! Clive, no problem, still appreciate your input. Can Jimmajamma's replay be made into a full answer?

Comment: @clive, why don't you just edit your answer accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to creating a pre-process function in your template, you can print the value of the site name variable in a block using this php snippet in your block

```
<?php
$site_name = variable_get('site_name');
echo $site_name;
?>
```

So, to print a copyright notice that includes your site name, it would look something like:

```
©copyright <?php echo date('Y');?><?php $site_name = variable_get('site_name'); echo "&nbsp"; echo $site_name; echo", "; ?> All Rights Reserved.
```